# Grid search does not choose optimal results when using a different number of features based on RFE

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am using Grid search for an **SVM-RFE** predicting a binary outcome with 33 features.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =
train_test_split(df[df.columns.difference(['label'])], 
                                                df['label'], 
                                                test_size=0.2, 
                                                random_state=42,
                                                shuffle=True,
                                                stratify= df['label']
                                                )
 print(f'The training dataset has {len(X_train)} records.')
 print(f'The testing dataset has {len(X_test)} records.')
 #The training dataset has 461 records.
 #The testing dataset has 116 records.

 pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('wz',Winsorizer(capping_method='gaussian', tail='both', fold=3)),
                   ('standardscaler', MinMaxScaler()),
                   ('feat_sel', RFE(estimator=SVC(kernel='linear'))),   
                   ('svc',SVC(kernel='linear'))
                   
                  ]
           )
param_distributions = {
                   # specify here the number of features you want to test using the RFE method
                   'feat_sel__n_features_to_select': [10] ,
                   # ... other parameters you want to search ...
                   'svc__C': [1,10,100,1000],                       
                   'svc__class_weight':['balanced'],
                   'svc__gamma': ['auto'],
                   'svc__probability': [True]}

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42) 
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe,
                        param_grid=param_distributions,
                        cv=kfold, 
                        scoring ='f1',
                        refit=True, 
                        n_jobs=-1, 
                        verbose=1
                       )
grid_result=search.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(f'The best hyperparameters are {grid_result.best_params_}')
pred=search.predict(X_test)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, pred))
```

As you can see above when I run fit and predict with **fixed number of features** (10 features), I get the following results:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.84      0.70      0.76        76
       1       0.57      0.75      0.65        40
```

But with a ** different number of features** grid search chooses 33 features.

```
'feat_sel__n_features_to_select': [10,15,20,33]
```

And I get the following results:

```
           precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.79      0.64      0.71        76
       1       0.50      0.68      0.57        40
```

Why did the grid search not choose the optimal result?

I read this [article1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438764/gridsearchcv-not-choose-the-optimal-result) and the [article2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64256966/grid-search-not-giving-the-best-parameters), but I think those are about a different problem. Did I miss something?

Comment: Where are those results tables coming from?  A separate test set?

Comment: See also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/82028/55122

Comment: No, The only thing that has changed is the number of features. To clarify, I added some information in the first part.

Comment: Might be a local minimum.  Grid search isn't always the same thing as exhaustive.
I don't see a seed in your grid search CV.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add this but I used set seed and grid search cv results are reproducible.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my code? Optimal number of features is 10 or 33?

Comment: Right, so the classification reports **are** on some separate test set. Then it may well be that the best hyperparameters in terms of cross-validation on the training set aren't the best on the test set. This is particularly true if the train and test sets are statistically different, as mentioned in the second paragraph of the accepted answer to my linked question. But even without that, the difference might be chalked up to just random variation.